# How would I search for an bibliographical link which is no longer available?

Tags: citations, online-publication, online-resource

I was searching data in regard to the strength of magnetic fields and got a a bibliographical link to what I was searching. Regrettably, the link is no longer functional and is on a language in which I am not proficient (German). How could I find a valid link?

Link:[Strongest continuous magnetic field produced by non-superconductive resistive magnet](https://www.ru.nl/nieuws-agenda/nieuws/vm/imm/vastestoffysica/2014/38tesla/@936560/hfml-sets-world/)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Seems more likely to be Dutch than German, given the .nl domain (and, indeed, it is Dutch, but you should look at the English language pages instead if you don't read Dutch). You could try the wayback machine and see if they have a copy. Given the 2014 date it is not surprising that it has vanished into the void...

Answer (score 5):

It was captured [here](https://www.ru.nl/nieuws-agenda/nieuws/vm/imm/vastestoffysica/2014/38tesla/@936560/hfml-sets-world/) at archive org on Jul 6, 2019.